# Server-sent events inside Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement the HTML5 Server-sent events inside Laravel 4, I found this [repo](https://github.com/motyar/mchat)

the script uses `server.php` file to get it working. My question is how would I implement it to get it working with a Controller instead of a plain php file? So  in the Javascript side it will look like this:

`var source = EventSource('/notifications');`

I tried this just to see if I get a response:

```
class NotificationsController extends BaseController {

public function index()
{

   $response = Response::view('notifications.index');

   $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
   $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

   return $response;
}
```

}

and in the view:

```
<?php

  echo "id: 4" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: this is a message" . PHP_EOL;
  flush();
```

Finally I get this error in google-chrome network panel:

```
caution: provisional headers are shown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, the solution was quite simple:

the `JavaScript` in the main Layout:

```
  var source = new EventSource('/notifications');
  source.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

in the `NotificationsController@index`:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


if (true)
{
  echo "data: <p> Hello There </p>\n";
}

flush();
```

I got back the MessageEvent !