# Laravel 5: Use Server-Sent Events to push messages to browser

Tags: php, laravel-5, server-sent-events

I've looked at [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472423/server-sent-events-inside-laravel) and [This article](http://zrashwani.com/server-sent-events-example-laravel/#.VSaAOuEntFu) to try and implement Server-Sent Events in *Laravel 5*. Though, between the two, I can't figure how push updates to the client based on an event. In this case, the event is a ClientException being thrown. A ClientException in my application is caused by a user made error. When one is thrown, I want to push an update to the client that populates a universal error panel.

Here's what I have in my blade:

```
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("{{ route('globalmessages') }}");
    source.addEventListener("message", function(e)
    {
        $("#errors").html(e);
    }, false);
</script>

<div id="errors">
</div>
```

The EventSource successfully hits the the controller action:

```
public function pushErrors()
{
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function()
    {
        $errors = ???; // How do I populate this
        if (!empty($error))
        {
            echo $error;
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
        else
        {
            \Log::info("No errors to push");
        }
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    return $response;
}
```

And the error handling happens in Handler.php@render:

```
if ($e instanceof ClientException)
    {
        $message = $e->getMessage(); // Need to send this to client
        return \Response::json([]);
    }
    else
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

So, what I need to do is somehow give the errors to the controller route. I tried using a singleton, but I couldn't get that to work. I tried giving the controller a field to hold it, but that was always empty.

On top of that, this current implementation seems to be running every 5 seconds. I'd like to be able to call a function when the ClientException is thrown to push the update.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Some more info:

Here's the controller action that renders my page:

```
class HomeController
{
    public function getHome()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

My controller using an infinite loop:

```
class MainController extends RouteController
{
    public function pushErrors()
    {
        $response = new StreamedResponse();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');

        $response->setCallback(
            function()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    $error = MessageQueue::dequeue();
                    if (!empty($error))
                    {
                        echo 'data: ' . $error. "\n\n";
                        ob_flush();
                        flush();
                    }
                    sleep(1);
                }
            });

        return $response;
    }
}
```

If I take out the while loop, this code works, in that the message is pushed, the connection dropped, then re-established and pushed again. With the while loop, the page just hangs.

My routes:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI            | Name           | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | globalmessages | globalmessages | App\Http\Controllers\MainController@pushErrors   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | /              | /              | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@getHome      |            |
|        | POST     | login          | login          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@postLogin    |            |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

HomeController@postLogin is the route that I call to that generates the ClientException.

Comment: Can you update your HTML to show the route you are connecting the EventSource object to? `errors` is not listed as a route in your dump. You also have the `globalmessages` route pointing to `MainController@pushErrors`, the action you have in your controller is `pushMessages()`, which is it?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the typos.

Answer (score 4):

Your controller is missing a key function from the article. In the article, the controller is doing an endless loop. In the endless loop, the data is checked for similarity, if the data has changed then the buffer is flushed and written so that the client JS can read it.

How I would implement this is to create a table that holds all your ServerSentEvents, then in my controller query from that table and retrieve the rows which have not yet been sent.

In this example, we will check if there is any data in our `$data` array, and send it to the client if there is.

```
DB::table('ServerSentEvents')->where('sent', 0)->get();
```

Will return a empty array if there are no rows returned from the query.

```
public function pushErrors() {

$response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function() {

    $data = $this->getData();

    while (true) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            echo 'data: ' . json_encode($data) . "\n\n";
            ob_flush();
            flush();

            /* update the table rows as sent */
            $ids = [];
            foreach($data as $event){
                $ids[] = $event->id;
            }
            DB::table('ServerSentEvents')->whereIn('id', $ids)->update('sent', 1);              
        }

        //sleep for 3 seconds
        sleep(3);

        //requery for new events that need to be sent
        $data = $this->getData();
    }

});

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    return $response;
}

public function getData(){
    $data = DB::table('ServerSentEvents')->where('sent', 0)->get();
    return $data;
}
```

You also need to insert new rows into your database when the ClientException occurs:

```
if ($e instanceof ClientException)
{
    DB::table('ServerSentEvents')->insert(['message' => $e->getMessage(), 'sent' => 0]);        
}
else
{
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Depending on what kind of information you want based on your events you may need to add or remove more columns to the ServerSentEvents table.

The ServerSentEvents table is a table you will need to create, I didn't provide a structure here because there may be more information you want to save in the rows, and the overall concept of pulling the data from the database is the point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are two issues, though: 1. I wanted to avoid the loop. I would have preferred to just be able to call a function at the time the exception is caught that would send the data to the client. 2. I was trying to avoid storing these in the database. These errors are things such as "You can't use that value" or "You don't have rights to do that". Things that you'd normally just get from an ajax call and through on the screen. Storing them in the db seemed like unnecessary overhead. Also, my callback function does run every 5 seconds, without using the loop.

Comment: With php an http request is made to your server by the browser, your web server (probably apache) will execute the php code, without the loop, the code executes normally and the response is sent to the browser. 

This is why you need the loop. The loop keeps the connection between the client and the server open, otherwise the client makes the request and then receives the normal http response. The loop is a fundamental concept of long polling.

Comment: You can't just "send the data to the client", if there is not a already established connection between the client and the server. HTTP has a life cycle where the request is made by the browser, and then the response from the server is sent to the browser. The server cannot initiate a connection between the server and the client browser, that is why long polling is used to keep a connection open, which mimics "real time" communications. This is at least true with PHP when using HTTP based method, with compiled languages it may be different.

Comment: As for not persisting the data in a database, you need to be able to persist the data somewhere, if you wan't you can write it to a JSON file and then read from the file in the loop. There is no persistent state in PHP as with every request the code is interpreted and then executed. Each time the code runs, all the variables are new, and will not hold values from previous calls / executions without loading those values from a file, database, or other persistent store.

Comment: The only alternative to persisting in a database or file would be to use something like Redis or Memcache. Laravel supports both through its cache drivers. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache . Hope that provides some more insight / help!

Comment: Just for kicks, I used the File I/O setup. When I don't use the loop, the event fires every 5 seconds and everything works fine. When I add the loop to fire every one second, my page never loads. This makes the server unresponsive until I kill it.

Comment: The event fires every 5 seconds because the javascript client identifies that it lost connection and needs to reconnect. Because it there is no loop the connection always closes. To clarify, you need 2 routes. The first route will render your client html and create the js client connection, the second route points to your controller and sends the messages to your client. If you visit the same route that the send events client is connecting too, it will never load, because of the endless loop. Thats the whole point of the loop.

Comment: The route that renders the page is called getHome. The pushErrors route is only accessed via the Javascript EventSource.

Comment: So with the endless loop, the getHome route never loads? Odd. Can you update your question the routes and controller code too?

Comment: I've added more info.